# broken packages reinstallation problem on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: package-management, dpkg

Update notification on Ubuntu 18.04 show message

```
You have 2 broken packages on your system? Use the 'Broken' filter to locate them
```

I opened Synaptic Package Manager
searched broken
select **python-zone.broken**
process start
reflects error message

```
E: /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-kHDkyn/0-perl_5.26.1-6ubuntu0.5_amd64.deb: 
subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
```

retried to open Synaptic Package Manager but not opening need  help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `fix-missing` option with `apt update` to run the updates and ensure the packages are up to date and there is no new version available for the packages.

```
sudo apt update --fix-missing
```

Once you are done with the update, execute the below command to force the package manager to find any missing dependencies or broken packages and install.

```
sudo apt install -f
```